# Tabletools set sSwfPath in Django

Tags: django, datatables, tabletools

How do I set the path for sSwfPath in Django?

```
$('#rTable').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    destroy: true,
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip', 
    "tableTools": {           
       "sSwfPath": "/static/copy_csv_xls.swf"
    }
});
```

I am loading my js and css files from static folder. It doesn't seem to be working for the swf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an absolute path by using the [**CDN**](http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/) :

```
...
tableTools: {           
    sSwfPath: "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
}
```

Comment: Django doesn't do well with CDN

Comment: @randomnessrandomly, ????? Yes it does, because it is an absolute path. If you have problems with the above URI you have problems with any external resource, and then it is not django that is the problem, but a firewall or other restrictions on your local network.